# Javaw.exe won't run .jar file while java.exe will

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have a java app that I wrote. I am able to execute it using Ant and with "java -jar" from the command line. I want to be able to launch the file using "javaw.exe" (my app uses Swing). For some reason it doesn't seem to do anything (javaw starts for a second and then quits with no error that I can see). I tried running the same file on my Win XP computer using javaw and it executes fine. The other computer I am using it on is a Win 7 laptop.

Comment: Boil this down to the minimum. Does it fail with just a main class and an empty main method? If not, keep adding bits of your app back until it breaks in javaw again. Post your findings. I doubt you'll get very helpful answers with the detail provided so far.

Comment: I've had this problem if I had some console input still active in the code (testing purposes etc.) and forgot to remove it. Try piping the output to a file (javaw.exe ... file.jar > file) and see if anything pops up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on purtip31's comment ...

I expect that the problem is that some exception or error is occuring when you launch using `javaw`, but you can't see any diagnostics because they are going nowhere.

- In the short term, redirect standard output to a file and look at what is being written.
- In the long term, replace your "System.out" and "System.err" diagnostics with proper logging via a logging framework such as log4j, java.util.logging, etc.

Comment: I logged to a file and found that I was getting some errors that have to do with how I wrote my code. Thanks.